# OpenGL - Stencil Test in a Rectangle

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, stencil-buffer

I am planning to draw a rectangle with a hole in its center. I am trying to use the stencil test on it but I can't make it work. You can see below for how I do it.

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glColorMask(GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 2, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE, GL_REPLACE);
// Draw the rectangle here
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 2, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_INCR, GL_INCR, GL_INCR);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would much be appreciated! :)

Comment: This just sets up writing `2` into the stencil buffer (assuming it's deep enough), then the "draw here" code which will write that `2` wherever it draws, and then sets up the stencil to only draw where the `2` was written. This doesn't match the textual description much. Can you show a more complete (pseudo-)code example?

Comment: @Angew - This is the only code I have for the stencil test. I am new to this and I would really want to learn how it should be done. The "draw here" is just a simple binding of buffer to opengl and calling the glDrawArrays. There is nothing more I can give to you from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your situation is that you already have something drawn in the framebuffer, and now you want to draw a rectangle with a hole in it, so that it does not cover what's underneath the hole, but covers what't underneath the non-hole part.

Logically, this means you first draw the *hole* into the stencil buffer, and then use the stencil test to *exclude* those fragments when drawing the rectangle.

In code, it looks something like this:

```
glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

// Fill stencil buffer with 0's
glClearStencil(0);
glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

// Write 1's into stencil buffer where the hole will be
glColorMask(GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);
drawHoleShape();

// Draw rectangle, masking out fragments with 1's in the stencil buffer
glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glStencilFunc(GL_NOTEQUAL, 1, ~0);
glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
drawRectangle();

// Cleanup, if necessary
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

Of course, you can use `2` (or any other stencil bit/value) instead of `1`.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I will try this first :)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have followed the algorithm above and it seems whatever I draw in the drawholeshape disappears and the only thing that I can see is still the whole rectangle.

Comment: @zyneragetro Something just occurred to me - have you actually created a stencil buffer in your context? E.g. when using GLUT, it would be done by adding `GLUT_STENCIL` to the arguments of `glutInitDisplayMode`.

Comment: Nope. What you have given to me above is the only thing I wrote. What happens when you create a stencil buffer?

Comment: @zyneragetro You can use it. You can't write into a stencil buffer if you don't have one.

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to find what is the equivalent glutInitDisplayMode when not using GLUT.

Comment: @zyneragetro OK then, *what* are you using instead of GLUT? BTW, please don't expect me to magically provide a 100% complete solution with all the t's crossed and i's dotted; that's not what SO is for. I am more than happy to help out, but I expect research and effort from your side as well.

Comment: Wait. I am confused now but in my header I import this OpenGL/gl.h, I tried the glutInitDisplayMode but it won't work, I searched and can't seem to find anything yet and also no worries as I don't expect you to answer everything :)

Comment: @zyneragetro GLUT is not part of GL itself, it's a small utlity library for managing related-but-not-GL stuff like window and context creation. What are you using to get a GL-capable window on screen? It is in *that* that you must somehow enable the stencil buffer.

Comment: I am using EGL and until now I can't find how to enable the equivalent of GLUT_STENCIL. I am still researching and reading documentations about how to do it.

Comment: @zyneragetro I've never used EGL, but browsing the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.5.pdf), it seems you should look into things like `eglChooseConfig` and `EGL_STENCIL_SIZE` (section 3.4).

Comment: Thanks :) I will just update you once I found the right thing to used. Thank you for the patience and time :D

Comment: Using the above answer you posted plus the information you have given about enabling the stencil buffer, my problem is solved! Thanks :)